# REDIS server requirements for BlueDomino hosting

Tags: redis

I have a Python / REDIS service running on my desk that I want to move to my Blue-Domino-hosted site. I've got Python available on the server, but not REDIS. They don't give me root access to my Debian VM so I can't git, extract, and install myself from a Unix prompt.

Their tech support might do the install for me, but they need me to point them to server requirements, which I don't see on the REDIS download page.

I could probably FTP binaries to the site if they were available, but that's dicey.

Has anyone dealt with this?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Redis is actually quite easy, from source. It doesn't have any dependencies, so just download the tarball, unzip it, and follow the install instructions. I'm always afraid of doing that sort of stuff, but with Redis it really was a breeze. If you don't dare to do it their tech support should be able to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. It's something I've been wanting to tackle for a bit. Now seems like the time.

Answer (score 1):

If it is Intel/AMD server, you can compile the Redis somewhere (32 bit version for example), and upload it as binary. Then start it with Python. I did this myself couples weeks ago.

For port you will need to use something over 1000. I don't recommend to use default port. Remember to change LogLevel too. Daemonize works well as non-root too.

Some servers blocks all external ports, so you will not be able to connect to Redis from outside, but this will be a problem only if you connect from different machine. For same machine should be OK, since is "internal".

However, I am unsure how hosting administrator will react when he sees the process running :) I personally will kill it immediately.

There is other option as well - check service like Redis4you.com . But their free account is small, you probably will need to spend some money for more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Is your hosting provider looking for a minimum set of system requirements for running Redis? This is indeed not listed on the Redis website. Probably because there aren't many exotic requirements. Also it depends a lot on your use case. Basically what you need to run Redis is:

- Operating system: Unix like, Linux is recommended (one reason to favor Linux I've heard of is the performance of its TCP/IP stack)
- Tools: GCC, make, (git).
- Memory: lots (no seriously this depends on your use case, but because Redis keeps everything in-memory you need a least more RAM than the size of your dataset).
- Disk: disk access for making snapshots.

Comment: thanks for the thumbnail. I know my install on Windows was fall-off-a-log easy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be dealing with something non-traditional with my BlueDomino hosting. Since this project is a new venture, I think the best course for me is to rent a small Linux VM from rackspace and forget about the BD hosting.